# @SequenceGenerator not creating sequence in H2 database

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, h2

I have Student class:

```
@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "reg_num_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "reg_num_generator", sequenceName = "reg_num_seq", initialValue = 1000, allocationSize = 1)
    private Long registrationNumber;

    private String name;

    private String email;

    // getters and setters...
}
```

I am using H2 in-memory database. When I start my Spring Boot server, reg_num_generator sequence is not getting added in my H2 database.

Is it such that I need to create this sequence in H2 database first?

Comment: It turns out JPA will not auto generate until specified with @Id, so my use case is not applicable